# SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA): ERROR [22018] [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver][mysqld-5.1.51-community]

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-migration-assi

I am using SSMA for MySQL to migrate from MySQL to MSSQL and on several tables I am getting the 22018 error. After lots of mucking about I found that the error was being generated due to Russian characters being stored in these tables.

For example: `Бухгалтерский учет`

There are other non-English characters in the tables, such as `Profissão Jurídica` and they are coming through OK.

The error is to do with collation and the collation on the MySQL table is `latin1_swedish_ci` and the column that holds the "foreign" characters has `utf8_unicode_ci` collation on it and is a `varchar(255)`.

The recipient table in MSSQL uses the database default collation (`Latin1_General_CI_AS`) and the recipient column is a `nvarchar(255)`.

In SSMA the *charset mapping* for `latin1` is set to the default of `CHAR/VARCHAR` and I have tried having this set to `NCHAR/NVARCHAR` with no success. The *type mapping* for `varchar` is set to `nvarchar` for all instances.

The only thing close to an answer that I have found is [this posting](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/528e7363-fbba-4d0d-b2da-a326bf12e181/ssma-from-mysql-error-22018?forum=sqlservermigration). Unless I'm missing the point of the answer, I can't see that there is a missing conversion - or is there?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

After having spent literally hours trying to find out why it didn't work I found the solution when I started to give up and use a linked table in Access to the then a pass-through query into MSSQL.

I was using the wrong ODBC driver. It turns out there are 2 MySQL ODBC drivers installed an `ANSI` and a `Unicode` driver. I was using `ANSI`. When I swapped it to `Unicode` all was well!

[image: Unicode ODBC driver]

Answer (score 2):

As per the Microsoft SSMA help guide SSMA is compatible with only MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver (trusted).

I downgraded MYSQL ODBC from 5.3 to 5.1 and it worked.

MYSQL ODBC 5.1~ link 
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=415029

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I changed the driver type from ANSI to Unicode it worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).